# Inline functions, macros and other solutions to allocate on caller's stack

Tags: c

I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```c
int bufferSize = fooBufferSize(); // hate having to do this; this logic should be in `foo`
char buffer[bufferSize];
foo(buffer);
bar(buffer);
```

It happens all the time for me. In the wild, I see something similar a lot:

```c
int bufferSize = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, ...); // exact same issue as above
char buffer[bufferSize+1];
sprintf(buffer, format, ...);
```

Besides the fact that the above are tedious for the user to write, they also probably redo a lot of computations, which is not only inefficient, but it isn't DRY. I know that I could just malloc the buffer within foo, but there's a lot of issues with that: memory fragmentation, remembering to call free, overhead of malloc/free.

```c
char *foo() {
  char *buffer = malloc(...);
  // process the data in the buffer
  return buffer;
}

main() {
  char *buffer = foo();
  bar(buffer);
}
```

There are a lot of cases where I probably would use `malloc` (or a buffer pool) for things that are constantly removed and deleted (e.g. projectile objects in a game). However, the case that comes up a lot for me is that I want to allocate an object on the stack and then dispose of it when my function returns. The issue is that the object is generally allocated in a stack frame further down from the stack frame I want the object to live in. I'd prefer if I could just build on-top of the stack that `foo` uses. Like, what if I did this instead:

```
void foo(char **bufferPtr) {
  char buffer[...];
  // process buffer
  *bufferPtr = buffer;
  jmp __builtin_return_address(0); // pseudocode to jump to return address
}

main() {
  char *buffer = NULL;
  foo(&buffer);
  bar(buffer);
}
```

I don't even know the exact syntax to make this approach work, but it is both GCC-specific and extremely hacky. In addition, if the jump isn't understood by the compiler, local variable states might not be restored properly. I guess, what I really want is for `foo` to behave like a macro, e.g. like this:

```c
#define foo(buffer) \
    char buffer[4]; \
    strcpy(buffer, "hey"); 


int main() {
    foo(buffer)
    bar(buffer);
}
```

However, I really don't like using macros (terrible error messages, bad IDE support, slippery slope, etc.)

The macro above looks nice, but in my current usecase, I'm building a computation graph (similar to TensorFlow), and some of the node constructors would look really awkward using macros.

```c
typedef struct {
    float *data; // buffer to store output data of computation
    int order; // number of dimensions
    int *dimensions; // e.g. [3,4] for a 3x4 matrix
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node super; // it's still a node, so just pass a ref to this whenever you need a Node*
    Node *A;
    Node *B;
} MatMulNode;


void printMatrix(const char *name, Node *node) {
    assert(node->order == 2);
    printf("%s: [%d x %d]\n", name, node->dimensions[0], node->dimensions[1]);
}

// look at all these backslashes
// also, `return -1` might not make sense in the context this macro is used.
#define matmul(node, left, right) \
    if (left.order != 2 || right.order != 2) {\
        return -1;\
    }\
    if (left.dimensions[1] != right.dimensions[0]) {\
        return -1;\
    }\
    int dimensions[2];\
    dimensions[0] = left.dimensions[0];\
    dimensions[1] = right.dimensions[1];\
    float data[dimensions[0] * dimensions[1]];\
    MatMulNode node = {\
        .super = {\
                .data = data,\
                .order = 2,\
                .dimensions = dimensions,\
        },\
        .A = &left,\
        .B = &right,\
    };

int main() {
    Node A = {
            NULL,
            2,
            (int[]) {1, 2}
    };
    Node B = {
            NULL,
            2,
            (int[]) {2, 3}
    };
    matmul(C, A, B);
    printMatrix("A", &A);
    printMatrix("B", &B);
    printMatrix("C", &C.super);
}
```

I'm honestly surprised by how well this works, but I also hate the fact that I have to use macros for it and refuse to believe that this is the best API I can make which avoids malloc.

I tried using inline functions, but `inline` is just a suggestion unless I'm using the `always_inline` attribute (but that's GCC only), and AFAICT, it doesn't seem to work with `alloca`. I'm not even sure if the below code has defined behavior, or if I'm just getting lucky:

```c
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) Node *matmul(Node *left, Node *right) {
    if (left->order != 2 || right->order != 2) {
        return NULL;

    }

    if (left->dimensions[1] != right->dimensions[0]) {
        return NULL;

    }

    int dimensions[2];
    dimensions[0] = left->dimensions[0];
    dimensions[1] = right->dimensions[1];
    float data[dimensions[0] * dimensions[1]];
    MatMulNode node = {
            .super = {
                    .data = data,
                    .order = 2,
                    .dimensions = dimensions,
            },
            .A = left,
            .B = right,
    };
    return &node.super;
}
```

The final approach I know of is to use continuation-passing style, e.g.

```c
void matmul(Node *A, Node *B, void callback(void *, Node *C), void *context) {
    MatMulNode C = ...;
    callback(context, &C.super);
}
```

The obvious tail-call optimization of this approach is nice, and the fact that the stack is obviously preserved would make it much less hacky than things like `jmp`, but the API that it presents to the user is really ugly. For example, what if I want to do `matmul(A, matmul(B, C))`? The code I'd have to write is extremely counter-intuitive, especially because I have to pass in a `context` variable to the callbacks, when they should Ideally just have access to the entire stack and choose whatever variables they need from there.

```c
void callbackABC(void *context, Node *ABC) {
    assert(ABC->order == 2);
    printf("A(BC) is [%d x %d]\n", ABC->dimensions[0], ABC->dimensions[1]);
}

void callbackBC(void *context, Node *BC) {
    Node *A = context;
    matmul(A, BC, callbackABC, NULL);
}

int main() {
    Node A = {
            NULL,
            2,
            (int[]) {1, 2}
    };
    Node B = {
            NULL,
            2,
            (int[]) {2, 3}
    };
    Node C = {
            NULL,
            2,
            (int[]) {3, 4}
    };
    matmul(&B, &C, callbackBC, &A);
}
```

Overall, I think that inline functions are the closest thing to what I want, but rather than ask "How do I force a function to always inline?" I figured I'd ask with the full context of what I want to achieve and why none of my solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending it, but also you may want to take a look at the `__attribute__ cleanup(freefunc)` feature in gcc. Basically handles cleanup when the associated variable leaves scope.